# Getting longitude east or west direction on route

Tags: php, math, latitude-longitude

I am trying to find the actual longitude direction on a route.

For example the route could be:

37.635118, -75.058594 (US EAST COAST) to 38.740377, -123.222656 (US WEST COAST)

In this case, the direction would be WEST, as EAST would be across the world.

Using the following distance calculator i would like to return the actual direction as well, but i am uncertain as to how i can do that.

```
function getdistance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2) {
  $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
  $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) *   cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
  $dist = acos($dist);
  $dist = rad2deg($dist);
  $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  $res = round(($miles * 1.609344));
  return $res;
}
```

Does anyone know how i would go about getting the W/E direction from the coordinates above?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i realized it was alot simpler than i thought.

$lon1-$lon2 will return either a positive or negative, and from that, its easy to find that any positive number is east, and negative is west.